# Add filter in Netsuite report by script

Tags: netsuite

I have a button called "Show Report" on Project record. I called a report url on that button by client script. I have to set Project filter on that report so that I can see the report of the same project. but I dont know how to pass the filter by script.
My client script code on button click

> 

```
var nShowReport = function(context){
    try
    {
        nUrl = '/app/reporting/reportrunner.nl?cr=555&reload=t&whence=';
        window.location = nUrl;
    }
    catch(err) {
        log.error({ title: strDebugTitle+' Error', details: err.message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is documented anywhere so it's really a matter of trial and error to figure out. The easiest way I have found is to go to a summary report and then click through to a customer and see what parameters it adds to the url.

It seems to be in the format below (replace `12345` with the internal id of the customer/project):

`/app/reporting/reportrunner.nl?cr=555&cj,custkeys,nkey,x,x,IN,x,x=12345`

Answer (score 0):

Report is not supported by SuiteScript. Provided that the data on the report is exposed as a column in saved search, I recommend using saved search instead and display the result using a suitelet.